# SSLEngine and close

Tags: java, networking, ssl, nio, sslengine

I've implemented an helper module that lets me obtain clean data from a channel used with SSL and write encrypted data into it: this is the relevant interface (I've also some non-abstract methods in that class, so doesn't say to me that "DataProvider should be an interface" ;)):

```
public abstract class DataProvider {
    // Notify the bytes read from the net
    public abstract void readFromNet(ByteBuffer b);
    // Gets the bytes to write into the net
    public abstract void writeToNet(ByteBuffer b);
    // Add a message to send
    public abstract boolean addMessage(byte[] data);
    // Obtains the application data received
    public abstract byte[] getReceivedApplicationData();
    // True if there is something to actually send over the wire
    public abstract boolean dataToSend();
    // True if we should close the channel
    public abstract boolean shouldClose();
    // Notify our intention to shut down the connection
    public abstract void shutDown(SelectionKey sk);
    // Set the interest op set for the channel
    public abstract void setInterestOps(SelectionKey sk);
}
```

I've an implementation of that abstract base class for SSL.
While testing that implementation, I've wrote two function: in one I receive a message with a SocketChannel and the SSLSocket used to send data closes the connection, in the other I send a message with the SocketChannel initiate the closing with that.
Now, the problem is that the SSLSocket used to receive the data doesn't close, even if I've issued those steps:

1. engine.closeOutbound()
2. engine.wrap()
3. channel.write(data) (yes, I'm sure I've sent all the data obtained with the wrap()
4. a select of the channel for reading the inbound close_notify

The problem is that the selector is stuck in the 4th step.

In the other test (SSLSocket closes the connection) I don't have a problem.

Note that I've implemented the shouldClose as:

```
return engine.isOutboundDone() && engine.isInboundDone();
```

so I need an incoming close_notify in order to close, even if I've initialized the close (I don't know if this is correct: eventually I can change it with `return engine.isOutboundDone()`)

This is my SSLSocket side of the code:

```
Socket toRead = socket.accept();
toRead.setSoTimeout(0);
InputStream is = toRead.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String read = "";
byte[] barray = new byte[1024];
while (read.length() < toSend.length() * 2) {
    int bytesRead = is.read(barray);
    bos.write(barray, 0, bytesRead);
    read = new String(bos.toByteArray());
}
assertEquals(toSend + toSend, read);
assertTrue(toRead.isClosed());
```

The last assert is violated.

Initially I've thinked that this is because there is no "background" thread associated with toRead, so I should do a read/write with it in order to consume the incoming `close_notify` and then finally get the socket close, but even that doesn't help.

Any idea?

Comment: I seriously recommending you use a framework like Grizzly or Apache MINA. You are mixing different programming paradigms.

Comment: What are those different programming paradigms I'm mixing together?

Answer (score 3):

Very late answer but you don't need wait for the close_notify if you have already sent one, see RFC 2246. However you should get one. You don't say how exactly you are selecting on close_notify.

NB Your code doesn't make sense. The socket will only be closed if *you* close it. `isClosed()` refers to the socket, not the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding `is.close();` before the fist assert.

Please note that this tiny piece of code I suggested doesn't close the socket. It's supposed to close the InputStream.

Comment: I can't close the socket: I've to receive the SSL's notify_end.

Comment: If you close the InputStream of Socket, you close the channel.
Since the documentation of SSLSocket doesn't "override" that information, I assume that the effect is the same.
Given the fact that I want to test if I've implemented the SSL close in a correct manner, I can't close the SSLSocket because I just want that it closes "for itself" at the receive of the ssl_close. I'm wondering why it doen't happens: this really is my question.